# MySql Update Query not working with EF6 in ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, sql-update, entity-framework-6

```
public void PostPlayerAttendance(int id, string attendance)
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var upd = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                    @"UPDATE dbName.Player SET Attendance = @Attendance WHERE Id = @Id",
                    new SqlParameter("Attendance", attendance),
                    new SqlParameter("Id", id));
            }
        }
```

also tried this:

```
@"UPDATE `dbName.Player` SET `Attendance` = @Attendance WHERE `Id` = @Id"
```

and this:

```
@"UPDATE 'dbName.Player' SET 'Attendance' = @Attendance WHERE 'Id' = @Id"
```

got this error:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored

Comment: Try with MySqlParameter instead of SqlParameter in your code.

Comment: @zed: I found it out as soon as I wrote the question. Anyway, thanks for the quick and correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing SQL statements and LINQ togheter. I suggest you use LINQ since you are working with the entity framework.

Your code should be like this:

```
public void PostPlayerAttendance(int id, string attendance)
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var query = (from player in ctx.Players
                             where player.ID == id
                             select player).Single();
                query.Attendance = attendance;
                ctx.SubmitChanges();    
            }
        }
```

Read about LINQ [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: I made it work. I know LINQ, but I'm using raw SQL on purpose. I want to master a classic then go for the rest.

Comment: @Tomo If you wanted to master a classic, then probably should have just stuck to pure ADO.NET rather than using EF.

Comment: @mason: I didn't say I want to master all the classics. Still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. *MySqlParameter* instead of *SqlParameter* and without *.dbName*.

```
var upd = ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(                        
                    @"UPDATE `Player` SET `Attendance` = @Attendance WHERE `Id` = @Id",
                    new MySqlParameter("Attendance", attendance),
                    new MySqlParameter("Id", id));
```